# I have an Website without SSL (HTTPS), do I need add to HEAD element a meta referrer unsafe-url?

Tags: html, http, ssl, https, seo

I have got Website without SSL certificate installed (HTTPS connection).

I saw few Websites that had implemented meta tag referer with value unsafe-url, like http://www.theguardian.com/ - which does not have SSL.

My Website (no SSL installed - all links with HTTP):

```
http://www.example.com/
```

Do I need to and should I add this meta tag:

```
<meta name="referrer" content="unsafe-url">
```

Inside my HEAD element?

Thanks!

Comment: https://moz.com/blog/meta-referrer-tag describes clearly how this tag should be used. From reading this you will see that the usage depends on the use case. Since you don't add enough information about your use case this question can not be answered.

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Well, if I add upper <meta> tag to my website (that has not got SSL installed) that uses HTTP, do I help other sites with HTTPS or not? Do they lose traffic if I have link in my article pointing to their HTTPS website? Or maybe do I lose traffic with/without this tag?
Is upper tag helping me or not? How about others? - that is what I did not understand good.
Thanks!